# End of previous quarter / last day of previous quarter

Tags: r, date-arithmetic, lubridate

Using `lubridate`, how to calculate the last day of the previous quarter for a given date?
The below formula doesn't seem to work for Nov 3rd, 2014 (other dates work)

```
library(lubridate)
date = as.POSIXct("2014-11-03")
date - days(day(date)) - months(month(date) %% 3 - 1)
# NA
```

Interesting enough, changing order works:

```
date - months(month(date) %% 3 - 1) - days(day(date))
# "2014-09-30 UTC"
```

Comment: The math is also wrong if you try with `"2014-03-30"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some possibilities with functions from packages `zoo` and `timeDate`, and `base` R. The `zoo` code was improved by @G.Grothendieck, and he also suggested the `base` alternative (thanks a lot!). I leave the `lubridate` solution(s) to someone else.

First, use `class` `yearqtr` in package `zoo` to represent the quarterly data. You may then use `as.Date.yearqtr` and the `frac` argument "which is a number between 0 and 1 inclusive that indicates the fraction of the way through the period that the result represents. The default is 0 which means the beginning of the period" (see `?yearqtr`, and `?yearmon` for `frac`).

Step by step:

```
library(zoo)

date <- as.Date("2014-11-03")

# current quarter
current_q <- as.yearqtr(date)
current_q
# [1] "2014 Q4"

# first date in current quarter
first_date_current_q <- as.Date(current_q, frac = 0)
first_date_current_q 
# [1] "2014-10-01"

# last date in previous quarter
last_date_prev_q <- first_date_current_q - 1
last_date_prev_q
# [1] "2014-09-30"
```

And a short version by @G.Grothendieck (thanks!)

```
as.Date(as.yearqtr(date)) - 1
# [1] "2014-09-30"
```

A nice `base` R solution by @G.Grothendieck

```
as.Date(cut(date, "quarter")) - 1
# [1] "2014-09-30"
```

Another possibility is to use `timeFirstDayInQuarter` and `timeLastDayInQuarter` functions in package `timeDate`:

```
library(timeDate)
timeLastDayInQuarter(timeFirstDayInQuarter(date) - 1)
# GMT
# [1] [2014-09-30]
```

Comment: Here is shorter version of the zoo solution: `as.Date(as.yearqtr(date))-1` and here is a solution that does not use any packages: `as.Date(cut(date, "quarter"))-1`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, So simple...Thanks a lot! I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but since this question specifically asks for a lubridate solution and I couldn't find working code for it elsewhere, I figured I'd post, keeping in mind that the base R solution is likely the most succinct:

```
> sampleDate <- ymd('2015-11-11')
> yearsToSample <- years(year(sampleDate) - year(origin))
> yearsToSample
[1] "45y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
> additionalMonths <- months((quarter(sampleDate) - 1) * 3)
> additionalMonths
[1] "9m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
> startOfQuarter <- ymd(origin) + yearsToSample + additionalMonths - days(1)
> startOfQuarter
[1] "2015-09-30 UTC"
```

Confirmed that this works for dates previous to the origin ('1970-01-01') as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure lubridate solution for 2021:

```r
> date <- ymd("2014-11-03")
> yq(quarter(date, with_year = TRUE)) - days(1)
[1] "2014-09-30"
```

Breaking it down:

```r
> # The year and quarter
> quarter(date, with_year = TRUE)
[1] 2014.4

> # The first day of the quarter as a date
> yq(quarter(date, with_year = TRUE))
[1] "2014-10-01"

# The day before the first day of the quarter as a date
> yq(quarter(date, with_year = TRUE)) - days(1)
[1] "2014-09-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the unit for year, month or quarter

```
floor_date(Sys.Date(), unit = "quarter") - 1
```